# MDT 2012 : Install Symantec EP 12.1 with Sylink

Tags: symantec

I want to deploy Symantec EP 12.1 with MDT 2012, but i have some query as We have two different sylink for Desktop and Laptop users, now whenever I deploy Symantec I can update only 1 sylink which is in installation folder. So is there anything, like script so we can install Symantec with proper sylink.

We are using Windows 7 x 64 OS, MDT 2012, Symantec EP 12.1, but Laptop hostname start from "IN-MU-LT-XXXXX" and Desktop start from "IN-MU-DT-XXXXX" So can we use any script to identify hostname and deploy apropriate sylink.

Please help !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy SEP on all the systems, irrespective of them being laptops or desktops and then create a group and sort laptops and desktops and then you can update sylink file on the group.